Prevent laptop Mediatek wifi card from connecting to a specific ap via mac address
It's a large wifi network across the campus with all one ssid but there is one 5ghz ap that is quite probamatic but my devices keep roaming to. Theres a nearby worse singal 5ghz  ap that's works normally but every time I connect to it via wifiinfoview it roams back to the probamatic one.
There's nothing in the device's settings to disable roaming so not sure what to do.
Device Manager

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
